# Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch 11.14

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I am on current Visual Studio Version 15.8.4 which contain Xamarin.iOS 11.14.0.13. Today I updated my Visual Studio for Mac and automatically updated Xamarin.iOS to version 12.0.0.15 (based on he Xcode 10 final release) which is not compatible. I get the following error:

> **Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch**
>
> The Xamarin.iOS SDK version installed on
> Max is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. Would you
> like us to install Xamarin.iOS '11.14' for you? This will overwrite
> any existing Xamarin.iOS installation on your Mac.

When I click 'Install' then the following error occurs:

> **Error**
>
> There were problems installing Xamarin.iOS '11.14'. Please try
> again and if the problem persists, try installing directly on the Mac
> and connect again.

On the mac I chose **Update channel: Stable**. I also tried the other channels withoud success. I am not able to install version 11.14 at all at the moment.

Is my only option to wait until they fix that version mismatch?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Currently, the preview is only available: https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-release-xcode-10-gm/

Comment: I am also getting this same problem. Followed the steps outlined here https://blog.xamarin.com/ios-12-and-xcode-10/ and now I am dead in the water and unable to connect to my Mac.

Comment: I get the same error with VS 16.5.2 and iOS SDK version 13.14.1.39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Version 15.8.5 fixes this. The [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.5) contain the following text:

> Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin now supports Xcode 10, which allows
>   you to build and debug apps for iOS 12, tvOS 12, and watchOS 5.

Comment: Luckily that didn't take long. At the time of my posts they still only had 15.8.4.

Comment: I had installed 15.8.7 and facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error after reading this blog post and following the upgrade suggestions.
https://blog.xamarin.com/ios-12-and-xcode-10/

But my first read through I missed this little tidbit.

"On Windows, Visual Studio 2017 will prompt for an update **as it rolls out**."

It appears as if the Visual Studio update might not be available yet. I allowed the prompt to downgrade the SDK and I can now connect again. My problem now is that I can no longer use the iOS Xamarin Simulator on my Windows machine. I get a device not found.

[image]

I figure the only way to fix this is to downgrade my Xcode back to 9. A workaround is to simply uncheck the "Remote Simulator to Windows" option in Visual Studio under Xamarin -> iOS Settings. That allows the simulator to launch my app on the Mac. I think I can live with this for now and hope that a new VS update is right around the corner.

Update: I also think it is important to mention that Matthew Clendening in the comments to the original post did provide a link to a preview release of the Visual Studio tools if any was unwilling to wait for an official release.

Update 2: We decided to try the [pre-release versions](https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-release-xcode-10-gm/) of the Visual Studio tools that Matthew linked above and did verify that Pairing works after installing them. If people are not spooked off by pre-release software then it is a viable option.

Update 3: I spoke too soon. I am able to Pair with my Mac with XCode 10 installed but still cannot get the Simulator to run on my windows machine so I am essentially back to where I was when I down graded Xamarin.iOS SDK to 11.4. I am going to dig more to see if this is an unrelated issue.

Last Update: So, overnight as Todd mentioned Microsoft released 15.8.5 and after upgrading, everything is working normally again. Lesson learned ... don't upgrade **ANYTHING** until **EVERYTHING** is ready.

Comment: VS for Mac and Windows Xamarin > iOS Settings can specify the Xcode path and working with multiple Xcode installations is [possible](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/working-with-multiple-versions-of-xcode-e331c01aa6bc)